# How to use stddev_over_time with grafana in time series

Tags: grafana

I have 2 metrics I am using to compute an error rate: `err_count/completed_count` and what I am trying to do is have a time series with an upper and lower band for anomoly detection. In more mathematical terms:

I want to plot +/- 10% std dev around the mean for a given data set; basically 2 horizontal lines. How can I do this in 1 query? If necessary, I can lookup the needed z-score and compute that

My query:

```
(
   { __name__ = "errored_count:ccmr"}/ 
   { __name__ = "completed_count:ccmr"}  
)
```

Here is the visualized output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single query. But it is possible  in three queries: original data, mean +10%, mean -10%.

Thos query would be:

1. `errored_count:ccmr / completed_count:ccmr`
2. `avg_over_time((errored_count:ccmr / completed_count:ccmr)[$__interval : ]@end()) * 1.1`
3. `avg_over_time((errored_count:ccmr / completed_count:ccmr)[$__interval : ]@end()) * 0.9`

Comment: Ah, almost. 10% about the mean stddev isn't exactly this straight forward, but you've given me some ideas. I don't know how to plot all 3 at the same time.

Comment: I ran number 3, but how do I get this to plot as a straight horizontal line?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, corrected answer, so second and third would produce constants. Not sure on you idea about stddev, so left avg for the time being.

Comment: `parse error: @ modifier must be preceded by an instant vector selector or range vector selector or a subquery`.  Direct C&P

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, corrected syntax.